# ggplot2 | How to plot mean lines for x, y, colour=group, facets=Drug~. Cannot make it look right

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataset with three factors (`Group`=Between; `Drug`=Within; `Session`=Within) and one response variable (`DEs2mPre`). I am able to plot faceted boxplot using

```
qplot(Session, DEs2mPre, data = Dummy.Data, colour = Drug, facets=Group~., -geom="boxplot")
```

I have three groups and two levels of Drug, so I get nice 3X2 graph with 3 individual graphs for each group with two levels of drug over the sessions on each graph. However instead of boxplots I would like to see lines connecting the means on each session. When I change geom to `geom="line"`, I get a mess of lines what looks like a line for every subject in the dataset and not a grouped (mean like) visualization of the data like what you would see with `lineplot.CI` (`sciplot` package).

Is there any way to do that in `ggplot2`?

Sorry I couldn't add my graphs because I do not have enough "reputation points".

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get a mess of lines since `ggplot` connects all data points by default. You need to tell `ggplot` to use the mean of each group instead. The appropriate arguments are `stat = "summary"` and `fun.y = "mean"`.

```
qplot(Session, DEs2mPre, data = Dummy.Data, colour = Drug, facets = Group~.,
      stat = "summary", fun.y = "mean", geom = "line")
```

Comment: thanks for a quick response. I still cannot make it work with your code, just get a blank 3 faceted graph space, everything is there but the lines. If I remove stat="summary" then I get vertical lines but with it I get no lines at all.