# ggplot: lineplot of means of two groups

Tags: r, ggplot2, mean, line-plot

I have searched and searched in the stacks for an answer to my question; [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13406654/ggplot2-how-to-plot-mean-lines-for-x-y-colour-group-facets-drug-cannot-ma) approaches my question but I have been unsuccessful in modifying the code to fix my graph.

I have data, reshaped in long format, that looks like this:

```
ID          Var1      GenePosition   ContinuousOutcomeVar
1           control      X20068492 0.092813611
2           control      X20068492 0.001746708
3           case         X20068492 0.069251157
4           case         X20068492 0.003639304
```

Each `ID` has one value for `ContinuousOutcomeVar` per position, and there are 86 positions and 10 IDs.  I want to plot a line graph with position on the x axis and the continuous outcome variable on the y axis.  I want two groups: a case group and control group, so there should be two dots for every position: one is the mean value for cases, and one is the mean value for controls. Then I want a line that connects the cases, and a line that connects the controls.  I know this is easy, but I'm new to R - I've been working at it for 8 hours and I can't quite get it right.  Below is what I have; I'd really appreciate some insight.  If this exists somewhere in the stacks, I really apologize...I honestly looked all over and tried modifying a lot of code but still haven't gotten it right.

My code:
 This code plots all the values for all IDs at each position, and connects them for the two groups.  It gives me a black dot at the mean of all 10 values per position (I think):

```
lineplot <- ggplot(data=seq.long, aes(x=Position, y=PMethyl, 
    group=CACO, colour=CACO)) +
    stat_summary (fun.y=mean, geom="point", aes(group=1), color="black") +      
    geom_line() + geom_point()
```

I can't get R to not plot all 10 points; just two means (one per case/control group) per position, with cases' & controls' values each connected by a line across the x axis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, adjusted your original sample data to contain more than one unique `GenePosition`.

```
dput(seq.long)
structure(list(ID = 1:8, Var1 = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("case", "control"), class = "factor"), 
    GenePosition = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L
    ), .Label = c("X20068492", "X20068493"), class = "factor"), 
    ContinuousOutcomeVar = c(0.092813611, 0.001746708, 0.069251157, 
    0.003639304, 0.112813611, 0.002746708, 0.089251157, 0.004639304
    )), .Names = c("ID", "Var1", "GenePosition", "ContinuousOutcomeVar"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

If you just want to represent one value for each `GenePosition` and `Var1` combination then it would be easier to calculate mean values before plotting. That can be achieved with function `ddply()` from library `plyr`.

```
library(plyr)    
seq.long.sum<-ddply(seq.long,.(Var1,GenePosition),
       summarize, value = mean(ContinuousOutcomeVar))
seq.long.sum
     Var1 GenePosition      value
1    case    X20068492 0.03644523
2    case    X20068493 0.04694523
3 control    X20068492 0.04728016
4 control    X20068493 0.05778016
```

Now with this new data frame you just have to give `x` and `y` values. `Var1` should be used in `colour=` and `group=` to ensure that each group has different color and that lines are connected.

```
ggplot(seq.long.sum,aes(x=GenePosition,y=value,colour=Var1,group=Var1))+
   geom_point()+geom_line()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for teaching me something new! Also learned that if I use "transform" with ddply instead of summarize it keeps all the other vars in my dataframe. I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

1、First make data as [Didzis Elferts](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1857266/didzis-elferts) support just like

```
data <- structure(list(ID = 1:8, Var1 = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("case", "control"), class = "factor"), 
    GenePosition = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L
    ), .Label = c("X20068492", "X20068493"), class = "factor"), 
    ContinuousOutcomeVar = c(0.092813611, 0.001746708, 0.069251157, 
    0.003639304, 0.112813611, 0.002746708, 0.089251157, 0.004639304
    )), .Names = c("ID", "Var1", "GenePosition", "ContinuousOutcomeVar"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

2、create a plot with code below:

```
ggplot(data,aes(x=GenePosition,y=ContinuousOutcomeVar,color=Var1,group=Var1))+
    stat_summary(fun = 'mean',geom = 'point')+
    stat_summary(fun = 'mean',geom = 'line')
```

Comment: Hi 孟泽楷, its probably better to create the summary stats separately as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15196901/11856430), because then you don't have to calculate the values twice (for the points and the lines). However, regardless that, your answer is missing the summary function within stat_summary(). I would suggest to adjust and share an output figure as well, thanks!

Comment: Hi Samson, I appreciate your kind advice. I think the code I provide is another solution, without any pre-summary. The missing args you mentioned, leaving it as default would be OK for this question. However, I provide the default mean by editing. The output figure is exactly same as the adopted answer's.